# Desrealizar Json de la siguiente api en vb.net

Tags: api, vb.net, rest

Hola comunidad buenas noches podrían ayudarme por favor estoy tratando de consumir la siguiente api:

https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees

el json devuelto es el siguiente

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "employee_name": "Tiger Nixon",
            "employee_salary": 320800,
            "employee_age": 61,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "employee_name": "Garrett Winters",
            "employee_salary": 170750,
            "employee_age": 63,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "employee_name": "Ashton Cox",
            "employee_salary": 86000,
            "employee_age": 66,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "employee_name": "Cedric Kelly",
            "employee_salary": 433060,
            "employee_age": 22,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "employee_name": "Airi Satou",
            "employee_salary": 162700,
            "employee_age": 33,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "employee_name": "Brielle Williamson",
            "employee_salary": 372000,
            "employee_age": 61,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "employee_name": "Herrod Chandler",
            "employee_salary": 137500,
            "employee_age": 59,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "employee_name": "Rhona Davidson",
            "employee_salary": 327900,
            "employee_age": 55,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "employee_name": "Colleen Hurst",
            "employee_salary": 205500,
            "employee_age": 39,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "employee_name": "Sonya Frost",
            "employee_salary": 103600,
            "employee_age": 23,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "employee_name": "Jena Gaines",
            "employee_salary": 90560,
            "employee_age": 30,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "employee_name": "Quinn Flynn",
            "employee_salary": 342000,
            "employee_age": 22,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "employee_name": "Charde Marshall",
            "employee_salary": 470600,
            "employee_age": 36,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "employee_name": "Haley Kennedy",
            "employee_salary": 313500,
            "employee_age": 43,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 15,
            "employee_name": "Tatyana Fitzpatrick",
            "employee_salary": 385750,
            "employee_age": 19,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "employee_name": "Michael Silva",
            "employee_salary": 198500,
            "employee_age": 66,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 17,
            "employee_name": "Paul Byrd",
            "employee_salary": 725000,
            "employee_age": 64,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 18,
            "employee_name": "Gloria Little",
            "employee_salary": 237500,
            "employee_age": 59,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 19,
            "employee_name": "Bradley Greer",
            "employee_salary": 132000,
            "employee_age": 41,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 20,
            "employee_name": "Dai Rios",
            "employee_salary": 217500,
            "employee_age": 35,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 21,
            "employee_name": "Jenette Caldwell",
            "employee_salary": 345000,
            "employee_age": 30,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 22,
            "employee_name": "Yuri Berry",
            "employee_salary": 675000,
            "employee_age": 40,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 23,
            "employee_name": "Caesar Vance",
            "employee_salary": 106450,
            "employee_age": 21,
            "profile_image": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 24,
            "employee_name": "Doris Wilder",
            "employee_salary": 85600,
            "employee_age": 23,
            "profile_image": ""
        }
    ],
    "message": "Successfully! All records has been fetched."
}
```

para deseralizar uso la siguiente funcion

```
Public Async Function GetEmployee() As Task(Of Object)
        Try
            Dim UrlApi As String = "https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees"
            Dim WebCliente As New WebClient()
            Dim JsonDevuleto As String = Await WebCliente.DownloadStringTaskAsync(New Uri(UrlApi))
            Dim ListaDevuelta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of EmployeeModel))(JsonDevuleto)
            Return ListaDevuelta
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {""name"":""value""}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[GestorGrados.EmployeeModel]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly." & vbCrLf & "To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object." & vbCrLf & "Path 'status', line 1, position 10.

¿podrían por favor ayudarme a consumir adecuadamente el API? gracias

Comment: Muestra la clase `EmployeeModel`

Answer (score 0):

EL *string* que te esta devolviendo no es una simple Lista de objetos, asi que no puede deserializarlo como lo estas haciendo,

Debrias tener las clases definidas de esta forma:

Añadir una cabecera contenedora como tal y como te devuelve la API:

```
Public Class Cabecera
    Public Property status As String
    Public Property data As List(Of EmployeeModel)
    Public Property message As String
End Class
```

El contenido imagino que lo tienes correctamente y seria este:

```
Public Class EmployeeModel
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property employee_name As String
    Public Property employee_salary As Integer
    Public Property employee_age As Integer
    Public Property profile_image As String
End Class
```

Y luego puedes deserializar simplemente usando la clase Cabecera

```
Dim ObjetoDevuelto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Cabecera)(JsonDevuleto)
```

Notar que no como he comentado al principio la api no devuelve una lista, y tu metodo en la firma devuelve un objeto por lo que seria posible devolverlo sin ma, si quieres que el metodo devuelva **una lista** deberias hacerlo de este modo:

```
Dim ObjetoDevuelto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Cabecera)(JsonDevuleto)
Dim ListaDevuelta = ObjetoDevuelto.data
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono perfectamente